# Angular (4): EventEmitter not working correctly between two components

Tags: angular

Here's my application component structure:

```
<company>
  <search></search>
  <action-panel></action-panel>
</company>
```

I'm trying to emit an event when a person presses a button on `<action-panel>` component, a function should be triggered in the `<search>` component.

**search-component.ts** function, which needs to be ran when a button in <`action-panel>` is pressed.:

```
public nextCompany() {
    const currentIndex = this.searchResults.indexOf(this.company);
    this.company = this.searchResults.find(item => this.searchResults.indexOf(item) === currentIndex + 1);
    console.log('Next Company');
    console.log(this.company);
  }
```

**action-panel-component.ts**

```
export class ActionPanelComponent {
  @Output() nextButtonEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {
  }

  public nextCompany() {
    console.log('pressed next button');
    this.nextButtonEvent.emit(null);
  }

  public deleteCompany() {
    this.companyService.deleteCompany(this.company);
  }

}
```

I've tried putting the `(nextButtonEvent)="nextCompany()"` into the `company` component tags, into the `<action-panel>`  tag but it doesn't work. The `nextCompany()` function of the `search-component` is never activated.

Comment: where do you call the `nextCompany()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *template referencing variable* to call the nextCompany method of search component:

```
<company>
    <search #searchComp></search>
    <action-panel (nextButtonEvent)="searchComp.nextCompany()" ></action-panel>
</company>
```

Comment: 11 more seconds :)